# What's causing my game to freeze in between loading new stages/areas?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Seemingly at random, my game freezes at the loading screen after I walk through a door, cave entrance, or other exit to get to the next area.  I end up having to open the task manager to terminate the game.  I have Dragonborn, Dawnguard, and various other mods installed.

Edit:  My game never freezes during a fast travel, while waiting, manually saving, or during the initial load when I start the game.

Comment: It is nearly impossible for us to diagnose random freezes without a great deal more info. What are your system's specs? What are these "various other mods" (As any single one or combination of mods could cause issues)?

Comment: @TrentHawkins  It wouldn't say anywhere near "nearly impossible".  With the limited information I provided, kotekzot was able to provide a solution that actually works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infinite loading screens are a result of poor memory management in Skyrim. The latest vesion of [SKSE](http://skse.silverlock.org/) can be configured to rectify this problem. To configure SKSE to fix Skyrim's memory management, add the following code to `Data\SKSE\SKSE.ini` in your Skyrim directory (create the files and folders if they don't exist).

```
[Memory]
DefaultHeapInitialAllocMB=768
ScrapHeapSizeMB=256
```

[SSME](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/50305/?) does the same thing.

Bonus: If you're using large mods, particular HD texture and high-poly mesh replacers, [ENBoost](http://wiki.step-project.com/ENBoost) will also help you avoid random crashes when the game exceeds its 2GB memory limit.

Bonus #2: Add the following code to SKSE.ini to make sure it removes script bloat from your saves left by uninstalled mods.

```
[General]
ClearInvalidRegistrations=1
```

Comment: Amazing.  After installing SSME, I have not had a single crash during loading screens between stages.  I knew coming to SE would be worth the time.